.NET 9 Debugger Step Over (F10) Behaving Like Continue (F5)
I'm experiencing an issue with debugging in .NET 9 after upgrading from .NET 8.
When using the debugger's Step Over function (F10), it most of the time behaves as if I pressed Continue (F5) instead.
What I've tried:

Created a fresh project file for my project
Tested in both Visual Studio and JetBrains Rider
Waited for potential early adoption issues to be resolved
Searched for similar issues online

Environment:

.NET Version: 9
IDEs: Visual Studio Community 2022 (17.12.1) and JetBrains Rider (2024.3)
Previous working version: .NET 8

Has anyone else encountered this issue or knows of a solution?

This is C# Winforms
A tiny console application works, but my project doesn't
a small windows forms project (new) also works
I can put a breakpoint in a random piece of code and it happens within 3 presses. (not function or class specific)
All software is up to date

Extra info:

I don't know how to reproduce it. I can't share my project
This project was using postSharp and i could see how that could be related. But i have removed postSharp + cleared Bin and Obj folders
This post is part of my own analysis. Seems very odd i am the only one.
I don't see any way my code could influence the debugger like that, so it seems like a Microsoft bug
This project started in .NET4.8 and has been upgraded to V5 V7 V8, so i have experience with upgrading
I will wait a little and see if i get responses here
Next logical step would be a bug report it think, anyway i will update this post in the future with my solution: this project will go to .net9 at some point. But right now this isn't a high priority.

Update:

I noticed hot reload was not working. (no errors, just no code
updates)
I'm back on Visual Studio 17.10 and back on SDK8
Hot reload is working again

Addressing the keymapping issues below in the comments:

Yes i thought of that too, i checked the key mappings and they are ok
I also tried using the menu, so actually clicking "step over" and same problem

Update:
It is a bug and I'm not the only one experiencing this: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/109885

Which version of VS, what sort of application? Can you reproduce this with a tiny console application consisting of a mere 3-5 lines of code? (You say you've tried creating a fresh project to isolate the issue, but you haven't told us what the results of that were...)

i have added the info in the "edit" of my post

What version (and edition) of Visual Studio?

Visual Studio (community 17.12.1) and JetBrains Rider (2024.3)

So does a "File > New Project" WinForms project (with a small amount of extra code) demonstrate the problem? (Basically you need to tell us how to reproduce this.)

With the affected project open, can you open Tools -> Options -> Keyboard, and in the "show commands containing" field, type in debug and show us the command that has F10 assigned? E.g. https://i.sstatic.net/jt5KzSiF.png Just to confirm it's not set to the wrong command somehow.

Also, are you on a laptop using the integrated keyboard, or a desktop with a separate keyboard? Just to confirm there's no weirdness with F-keys on the laptop keyboard happening.

please check "Addressing the keymapping issues below in the comments"

I have the same behavior and my Debug.StepOver is set to F10. Thanks @Rowi123 you added the link to GitHub issue.
